# Получить значение cookie из html

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

есть текст:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
            document.cookie = binary.substr(binary.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+'4=sirius:ru:1760018168; path=/; expires=Wednesday, 18-May-33 03:33:20 GMT';
            document.location = "/manager/ispmgr";</script>
```

требуется получить:

**4=sirius:ru:1760018168**

**18-May-33 03:33:20 GMT'**

**/manager/ispmgr**

первое значение пытался получить вот так:

```
pattern = r"(document.cookie = ).+(\+')(.*)"
result_cookie = re.findall(pattern, string)
```

на выходе получалось следующее:

[('document.cookie = ', "+'", "4=sirius:ru:1276089620; path=/; expires=Wednesday, 18-May-33 03:33:20 GMT';")]

Но так и не смог понять как получить требуемый текст. Прошу подсказать

Comment: Сами-то пробовали?

Comment: Сам-то конечно пробовал. Пробовал вот так: pattern = r"(document.cookie = ).+(\+')(.*)"
result = re.findall(pattern, string)
print(result)

Comment: это html смешанный с script? а откуда берете файл, с какого сайта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

text = '''
<script language="JavaScript">
            document.cookie = binary.substr(binary.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+'4=sirius:ru:1760018168; path=/; expires=Wednesday, 18-May-33 03:33:20 GMT';
            document.location = "/manager/ispmgr";</script>'''

m= re.findall(r"[\"|']([^^\"|']+)[\"|']", text)
res = m[-2].split(";")
res.append(m[-1])
```

тогда в res будет:

```
['4=sirius:ru:1760018168',
 ' path=/',
 ' expires=Wednesday, 18-May-33 03:33:20 GMT',
 '/manager/ispmgr']
```